# How to add our trained data to existing Stanford NER classifier?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have to add my trained data to existing CRF classifier [english.all.7class.distsim.crf.ser]. 
Is there any API to extract the the existing models or de-serialise them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no: there is no way to recover the training data from the serialized model files. Nor is there a way to [easily] continue training from a serialized model. Part of this is by design: Stanford is not allowed to redistribute the data that was used to train the classifier. If you have access to the data, you can of course train with it alongside the new data, as per http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a